# Can I set spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts in code?

Tags: apache-spark

When I submit the application, I can specify the max try time to 1 by the following argument:

`--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1`

Is there any way to set it in code? I tried this way but it does not work -

`new SparkConf().set("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts", "1")`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share how are you creating sparkSession and sparkContext in your application?

Comment: `val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts", "1").setAppName("somename")`
   

`implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()`

Comment: Are you also creating SparkContext in code? If yes, can you share how are you creating the same?

Comment: No I did not create the SparkContext. I only created the SparkSession.